# What's the rails way for responding to just HTML in a controller with the format block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

Historically, I've been editing the default generated controller code in my rails block to remove the format block when I just respond with HTML:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.valid? and @message.save
      ...
      flash[:msgsent] = 'Your message was successfully sent.'
      format.html { redirect_to ... }
    else
      format.html { render ... }
    end
  end
end
```

becomes

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

  if @message.valid? and @message.save
    ...
    flash[:msgsent] = 'Your message was successfully sent.'
    redirect_to ...
  else
    render ...
  end
end
```

Is this OK? I know it works, but just didn't know the rails-way, or if it affects some use case I'm not considering.

To be extra safe, I guess I could add a restriction on the response to only .html requests.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that your controller action will ONLY respond to an HTML request (meaning it should reject JSON, XML...etc)? Or do you mean that, no matter what format is requested, it will always respond with HTML?

Comment: @Teeg, the former. Only respond to HTML, and reject JSON, XML, etc...

Comment: Gotcha. AdamT's or Mallanaga's answers are definitely good. I'll only add that if you remove the `format.html` and `respond_to` blocks, you will technically allow any request format (`.json`, `.xml` etc), but the client will simply receive your HTML, rather than the JSON or XML they were expecting. If that is acceptable, then you're fine.  However, if you want to give more explicit request feedback, I would keep the `format.html` as you originally had it. This, I believe, will result in a `406 not acceptable` if a request is made for anything other than HTML.

Comment: Thats a good idea. Would a respond_with controller-wide modifier be able to override the default response as well (send a 406 instead of HTML)?

Comment: Do you mean something like Mallanaga's suggestion, where you'd have `respond_to :html` in the controller, and `respond_with @some_model_object` in the action? Yes, if you're rendering some model in that way, as far as I know, it does indeed behave the same, with the 406 error for "non-supported" formats. However, if you meant whether the `respond_to` class method would override the whole `format.html` thing, in that case no the `respond_to` won't make a difference with anything you specify with the `format` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the way you are doing it is very common.

The `respond_to` block is if you want to provide web-service support. If you don't expect the action to respond to incoming json (or whatever) you don't need it.

You can read more about `respond_to` here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to

A side note (possibly just my opinion), the "generated code" you mention above is typically created via a `scaffold`. Many experienced rails developers tend to not use scaffolding when creating resources for their projects. The alternative to scaffolding is either to use the other rails generators `rails g model post` and `rails g controller posts`. Another option would be to manually create your controller files and either use a Model or Migration generator for the model.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `respond_with` and `respond_to`.

You're correct to kill those respond_with blocks.  You only need those (or my suggestions for that matter) if you're wanting a response in a different format than HTML.  :json, :js, :csv, :xml, etc.

So... if you need any other responses besides :html...
At the top of your controller, you put:

```
respond_to :html, :js

def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])

  if @message.valid? and @message.save
    ...
    flash[:msgsent] = 'Your message was successfully sent.'
    redirect_to ...
  else
    respond_with @message
  end
end
```

If you want to respond with json, you don't use respond_with (but you still need to add it to the list of `respond_with`:

```
render json: @message
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good way not store code which isn't used.
If you need render json, you just simply add it in future.

Comment: correct, that's what I'm going for. It's a good way, but is it the right way?

Comment: If you work in team, member which will join you will read you code, what he'll think when will see your code: "They use json for something" And will start to find "something" which there'are no. It's not problem on a small project, but when project is large it can become really problem. Thus we don't store unneeded code in our apps (ever commented).